# Fill area under geom_bspline()?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggforce

I see how `geom_area` is used to fill the area under straight lines. How do I fill the area under a curve such as one created by `geom_bspline`?

```
library("tidyverse")
library("ggforce")

dftest <- tibble(
  x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
  y = c(10, 15, 30, 80, 5)
)

# Fill area under straight lines - OK
ggplot(dftest, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  geom_area(alpha = 0.3)

# Fill area under curve ???
ggplot(dftest, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_bspline()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the stat paired with the area geom:

```
ggplot(dftest, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_bspline(geom = "area", alpha = 0.3)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, stats are calculations to performed on the data, while geoms are the manner in which the data are displayed. If you print the `geom_bspline` function, you can see that it passes `GeomPath` to the layer, so the `geom_bspline` function is just a convenience wrapper for `stat_bspline(geom = "path")`.